# Apply saturation to image behind <div> (only part of image) in CSS/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, css, ios7

I am making an iOS 7 style app in HTML/CSS/JS.  We are using a lot of tricky techniques and want to be able to animate elements, so I'm applying them all in HTML/CSS/JS rather than just using the raw image.

For blurs, I am using blur.js with really nice results -- you can blur only behind a `<div>` and then you can animate the div around it and looks really nice because the image only behind the div gets blurred.

Unfortunately, we are also applying a saturation filter in Photoshop, and I'm trying to replicate that.  It looks like everything on the web indicates you have to apply the desaturation to the image directly (via something like `-webkit-filter:
saturate(50%);`).  If I do this to the image directly, I can't animate the div behind it without the image behind it looking goofy.

Any way to apply a desaturation "layer"?  One brute force way I was considering was using the location of the div to determine where on the image to saturate, but worried this will destroy performance.

Comment: This might help you: http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/graphics/customfilters/cssfilterlab/

Comment: everything there is on the image itself, which doesn't answer the question

Comment: If you select `saturate`, you can drag the slider on the left to adjust the value. The text in the preview is *not* part of the image.